# Form opens before all data is fetched. How to make UI thread wait for first cycle of the processing thread to finish?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

My application fetches data from a live feed, processes it and displays the results. This data is updated every 5 seconds. In the Load event of Main form I've created a thread to show the splash screen which is shown until the first data cycle is run .

The data fetching and processing thread (RecieverThread) calls RecieveFeed. The isue I'm facing is that form2 which displays data fetched in RecieveFeed is shown before the first cycle is run completely. How do I ensure that form2 is loaded only after the first cycle has completed fetching data.

Code in the Main form:

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Hide();

      // Create a new thread from which to start the splash screen form
      Thread splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartSplash));
      splashThread.Start();

     //Thread to call the live feed engine. This thread will run for the duration of application
      ReceiverThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ReceiveFeed));
      ReceiverThread.Start();
      frmSecondForm form2 = new frmSecondForm();
      form2.MdiParent = this;
      form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
      Show();
      form2.Show();
    }   

    public frmRaceRace()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.splash = new SplashScreen();
    }

    private void StartSplash()
    {
        splash.Show();
        while (!done)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        splash.Close();
        this.splash.Dispose();

    }

    private void ReceiveFeed()
    {   

      while (!StopReceivingData)                    
      {
        foreach (...)
        {
         //Fetches data from live engine
         DLLImportClass.GetData1();
         //Manipulates and stores the data fetched in datatables                              
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate { StoreData(); }))
         rowsProcessed++;
         if (!done)
         {
          this.splash.UpdateProgress(100 * rowsProcessed / totalRows);
         }
        } 

       done = true;        
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need to use here is `System.Threading.AutoResetEvent`.  Basically, add a member of this to your form class:

```
private AutoResetEvent waitEvent_ = new AutoResetEvent(false); // create unininitialized
```

After showing your splash, you want to wait for this event to be signalled:

```
private void StartSplash()
{
    splash.Show();
    // this will time out after 10 seconds.  Use WaitOne() to wait indefinitely.
    if(waitEvent_.WaitOne(10000))
    {
        // WaitOne() returns true if the event was signalled.
    }

} // eo StartSplash
```

Finally, in your processing function, when you're done, simply call:

```
waitEvent_.Set();
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue of form opening before all data was fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got some race conditions in your code.

When doing threading with WinForms and most (if not all) UI frameworks, you can ONLY access the UI objects (forms and controls) from a single thread.

All other threads can only access that thread using .InvokeRequired() and .BeginInvoke().  These calls can be used to run a delegate in the UI thread.  See:

{REDACTED: StackOverflow will only allow me to post 1 hyperlink.  Google these}

There is a builtin shortcut for this in the BackgroundWorker class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Simply do this (Psuedocode):

```
public void StartSplash()
{
    Splash.Show();
    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    // set up bgw Delegates
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void bgw_DoWork( ... etc
{
    // do stuff in background thread
    // you cannot touch the UI from here
}

public void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted( ... etc
{
    Splash.close();
    // read data from background thread
    this.show();  // and other stuff
}
```

Now, you're guaranteed not to close the SplashScreen and not to start the main window before your data is delivered.

Other considerations: you'll probably need to use locks to secure the data you might access in the background thread.  You should never access data in more than 1 thread without locking it.

Comment: Actually, after reading your code in more detail, it seems like you want the background thread to keep running.  In that case you'll keep it running but use .BeginInvoke() to call the UI thread.  The UI thread doesn't need to do anything (just wait for events like normal).

Comment: Indeed there are Race conditions. However backgroundorker is for a single thread and I'm spawning multiple threads and using Threadpool.QueueWorkItem to manage them. Can I create a thread through BGW and then spawn multiple threads off it? This is the first time I'm working on threading and feel quite clueless. Also does ThreadPool have a maximum limit on number of threads that can be pooled?

Comment: BGW creates a thread of its own (or uses the threadpool most likely).  You could spawn more threads from within that but since it looks like you need to keep ReceiverThread running indefinitely it probably makes sense just to use a regular thread.  My point was that your splash screen should not try to block with a while loop.  That will make the UI unresponsive.  Rather you should just have it .Show() and then wait for an event.  Then the .BeginInvoke() (from the other thread) will be delivered like a system event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `frmMain_Load` to this:

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Hide();

     //Thread to call the live feed engine. This thread will run for the duration of application
      ReceiverThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ReceiveFeed));
      ReceiverThread.Start();
      frmSecondForm form2 = new frmSecondForm();
      form2.MdiParent = this;
      form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
      StartSplash();
      Show();
      form2.Show();
    }
```